# Table with 10 rows from a database JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

I wanna make a 10 rows table which contains data from database. For example, if there is 5 records in my database - the table should have 5 rows with data and 5 empty rows. I used JSTL foreach:

```
               <c:forEach items="${foo}" var="f">

                    <tr>
                        <td class="center aligned">${f.somethingId}</td>
                        <td class="center aligned">${f.somethingName}</td>
                        <td class="center aligned">${f.somethingDescription}</td>
                    </tr>
               </c:forEach>
```

For 3 records in database I should get something like this:

[image]

How can I make it in the simplest way?

Comment: use another loop, looping from `${foo.length}` to `10`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `c:forEach` until `10` (index 9 respectively) and check if the list size of `foo` is lower or equal to the current index. If so load the element and its value, otherwise render empty row elements:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="9">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{foo.size <= i}">
        <tr>
            <td class="center aligned">${foo.get(i).somethingId}</td>
            <td class="center aligned">${foo.get(i).somethingName}</td>
            <td class="center aligned">${foo.get(i).somethingDescription}</td>
        </tr>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{foo.size > i}">
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </h:panelGroup>
</c:forEach>
```